# Convert pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointCloudXYZI> to pcl::PCLPointCloud2

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very confused by the online documentation re this topic. I have a node with this publisher:

```
pointcloud_pub_ = nh_.advertise<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> > ("/cloud", 1, false);
```

In the callback, this vector is populated, then published.

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> cloud_xyzi_;
```

How can I simply convert `cloud_xyzi_` to `PointCloud2` at the final stage before publishing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201324/convert-pcl::pointcloud%3Cpcl::pointcloudxyzi%3E-to-pcl::pclpointcloud2/) by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2015-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't need to! Just include the following header:

```
#include "pcl_ros/point_cloud.h"
```

advertise your pointcloud_pub_ with type sensor_msgs::PointCloud2

```
pointcloud_pub_ = nh_.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("/cloud", 1, false);
```

and call publish give the point cloud with your explizit type:

```
pointcloud_pub_.pub( cloud_xyzi_ );
```

It should implizitly convert between the types.....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chris_](https://answers.ros.org/users/20918/chris_/) on 2015-01-20**:
thank you, thats excellent.

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2015-02-05**:
Is this the prefered way to fill a pointcloud2 message? I have a similar scenario where i have a C struct containing each points (x,y,z) values, and dont know how to directly fill the sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 msg